# Windows 10 permission issues with ubuntu server v 19.10 shared folder

Tags: server, permissions, windows

So I have ubuntu server v. 19.10 which I have setup for web hosting. I have created a folder on the server to share between the server and my desktop (windows 10 pro) so I can write websites and host them on my server. I have the folder mapped on the network which I can open on the windows 10 computer. I can create a basic html file in that folder, which I can open it with either notepad or view the file as a page, and copy it from the shared server folder to my desktop. I cannot, however, copy files into that folder from the windows side or edit any preexisting files that are created on the server side in that folder.

When I try to copy a file from windows 10 into that shared folder it says I need permission to perform this action. When I try to give all users (root, everyone, etc) full control on permissions as I only have 1 account on my desktop, it tells me "an error occurred while applying security information to: (the folder I have mapped). Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied." Basically Windows 10 is giving me a permissions battle. I have Samba setup on my server with the smb.conf file edited with the folder I created for sharing and mapped in the smb.conf file.

I have also tried giving root, and everyone full control on the permissions and it won't seem to let me do that.

Comment: Can you output `ls -la` on the directory, plus the permissions on your `smb.conf` file? Windows shouldn't be able to edit the permissions **on** the server, that's dictated **to** it.

Comment: I'm not trying to edit permissions on the server from windows. I am trying to give windows full control so I am able to drop html files onto the shared folder I have created on on the server folder I have mapped onto my network